# Seems to be a (minor) bug with displaying mathjax

Tags: bug, user-interface, mathjax

Hardly noticeable but I still decided to report it - just noticed: at [Find the number of boolean functions of n variable that satisfy the following condition](https://mathoverflow.net/q/232311/41291) one sees this

[image]

The second $k$ below is obviously spurious...

PS Added the link as suggested by [quid](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/9072/quid); the bug is not always there however, right now it reappeared after I reloaded that page.

PPS On Windows 10 pro I see this in Waterfox 44.0.3 and Chrome 48.0.2564.116 m (64-bit), have not tried any other browsers

**Later** - seen another instance of the phenomenon in the "Related" column of [Is this a model for $K$-theory of a triangulated category?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236707/is-this-a-model-for-k-theory-of-a-triangulated-category) which might shed some light on the nature of it. Result looks like

[image]

while the actual content of the garbled part should be ["Proof that the homotopy category of a stable $\infty$-category is triangulated"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55294/proof-that-the-homotopy-category-of-a-stable-infty-category-is-triangulated?rq=1)

Thus the whole thing is broken into columns in a wrong way somehow.

Also as pointed out by Martin Sleziak in a comment below this also happens on math.SE and physics.SE. At links provided by him there is a suggested solution by [Davide Cervone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/161253/davide-cervone) who seems to be one of the developers of MathJax

Comment: It may make sense in the related column of which question you had that title; if not it will be hard to see if it can be reproduced.

Comment: I've seen this happen every now and then, too.

Comment: @quid You are right, I should add this, the question was http://mathoverflow.net/q/232311/41291. I visited it again now and the thing was gone; however when I reloaded the page it appeared again.

Comment: Added, mentioning that it is not always there

Comment: This is very likely caused by something intefering with the CSS of the output from the AssitiveMML extension (which embeds visually hidden MathML for assistive technology). You can disable the extension via the MathJax menu (under math settings => math renderer). If you run into this again, it would be helpful if you could use the FF or Chrome developer tools to see what CSS is interfering. (Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it myself.)

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Sorry I don't know enough to figure out myself. When I inspect it, the stray $k$ is inside something called `<span style="font-family: MathJax_Math; font-style: italic;" id="MathJax-Span-8" class="mi">k</span>` which itself is inside `<span id="MathJax-Span-7" class="mrow">` which is inside `<span style="position: absolute;">` which is inside `<span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; height: 0px; font-size: 120%;">` which is inside `<span role="math" id="MathJax-Span-6" class="math">` which also holds the correct piece (with correct $k$)

Comment: What is involved seems to be called `inline:10` from `.MathJax span` but I have no idea how to get any further information

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. What I'm looking for is information in the panel names "styles" on the right-hand-side here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#dom-and-styles. For the element with `class="MJX_Assistive_MathML"` I'm hoping to find out if those styles (a section with the name of the class) are being overruled, in particular heigh, width, clipping etc. They would be struck out in the list and some other section in that panel would indicate what stylesheet is overriding them.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger There are indeed several lines overruled under `<span role="presentation" class="MJX_Assistive_MathML">`, of about 16 lines, 5 towards the end, 4 of those marked with "Invalid property value", namely `-webkit-touch-callout: none;`, `-khtml-user-select: none;`, `-ms-user-select: none;` and `user-select: none;`. It is fourth in the list, the first being `element` with no entries, the second `.MathJax span` with some lines overruled too, the third `.MathJax *` with two of five lines also overruled and marked "Invalid property value", then some other stuff... What must I seek?

Comment: Thanks for digging deep! Maybe we should move this to chat (though my day is coming to an end). Could you share a screenshot perhaps? I know the style panels can be rather long and it's difficult to know what's important.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger  Sure. I've got a screenshot (although not everything fits in it obviously, and I also have to leave soon). If you tell me how to arrange for chat and/or how to send you the screenshot I'll do it. Or we can postpone this if you prefer. Email is also an option.

Comment: Email sounds good. Can you ping me at peter.krautzberger@mathjax.org?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Only saw this now, sorry. I've sent to the gmail account that I found on your page, now forwarded here too.

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23073/mathjax-broken-in-related-section) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278752/titles-with-mathjax-break-in-the-related-questions)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes yes exactly. Seems like this is some diehard bug

Comment: In fact, if you believe [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278752/titles-with-mathjax-break-in-the-related-questions#comment902823_278752), the problem should be fixed soon: "Thanks for reporting. Fix is already in repo waiting for build. Should be live in < 24h."

Comment: @MartinSleziak It has become **much** more rare but occasionally I still encounter it :(